# Oracle SQL: COUNT DISTINCT BY newly created variable

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I want to count the distinct entries of `ID` by the newly created column `MONTH_YEAR` in order to get a table which stores the distinct values `MONTH_YEAR` (e.g. 07-2020) and the corresponding distinct count of `ID` (e.g. 2345). I used this code which does not work out:

```
SELECT TIME, to_char(TIME, 'MM-YYYY') "MONTH_YEAR", COUNT (DISTINCT ID) "IdCount"
GROUPBY MONTH_YEAR
FROM table
```

I think I have to create a new table with only the two mentioned values, haven't I? If that is true, how should I amend my code?

Comment: what do you mean with " does not work out"?  .. you have an error ?? show the error message. Wrong result  update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Ok, next time I will modify my question. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias cannot be used within the `GROUP BY` clause, and replace the order of `FROM` and `GROUP BY` clauses such as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(time, 'MM-YYYY') AS month_year, COUNT (DISTINCT id) AS "IdCount"    
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(time, 'MM-YYYY')
```

btw, all non-aggregated columns should be included in the `GROUP BY` list.